# Getting the name of a class constructed by an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I need to work inside a namespace, say I make this

```
var my_namespace = {}

my_namespace.my_class = function() {}

var instance = new my_namespace.my_class();
```

Then the current problem I'm facing is that instance.constructor.name returns "" (an empty string).

I want to check the type of instance by comparing it against an array of possibilities such as 'String' or 'Array' or 'my_namespace.my_class'

Theoretically I could work around it by using instanceof and eval but I'm looking for a less volatile way.

Comment: set a name property in your constructor?

Comment: No. You can use instance.constructor to get a direct reference, but it's an anonymous function so there's no way of getting its name.

Comment: I was thinking more of something like putting `this.className="Name"` in the constructor, so instance.className gives you the type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered not using an anonymous function? Something like:

```js
var my_namespace = {};
my_namespace.my_class = function MyClass() {};
var instance = new my_namespace.my_class();

console.log(instance.constructor.name);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply don't make it anonymous:

```
var my_namespace = {
    my_class: function() {}
};
var instance = new my_namespace.my_class();
console.log(instance.constructor.name) // "my_class" - since ES6 at least
```

But notice that relying on function names is a despised practice, it can fail in so many ways. If you really need tags, use them explicitly.

Comment: "If you really need tags, use them explicitly." yes do that!